# Unable to add quick replies after a function in Dialogflow inline editor fulfillment (Facebook messenger)

Tags: dialogflow-es, facebook-messenger

I can't seem to add quick replies after my messenger chatbot sends an email through an integration with sendgrid. I can add additional comments through agent.add(`text`), and can also send a card with a single button through agent.add(new card). However, quick replies through the suggestions fulfillment doesn't seem to be working for me.

I am using the inline fulfillment in Dialogflow and the bot is running on facebook messenger.

Code:

```
'use strict';
 
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const {WebhookClient} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');
const {Card} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');
const {Payload} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');
const {Suggestion} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');
const sgMail = require('@sendgrid/mail');

process.env.DEBUG = 'dialogflow:debug'; // enables lib debugging statements
process.env.SENDGRID_API_KEY = 'SG._fafgWTc';
  
exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  const agent = new WebhookClient({ request, response });
  console.log('Dialogflow Request headers: ' + JSON.stringify(request.headers));
  console.log('Dialogflow Request body: ' + JSON.stringify(request.body));
 
  
  
   function sendEmail(agent) {
    sgMail.setApiKey(process.env.SENDGRID_API_KEY);
    const emailParam = agent.parameters.email;
     
    const msg = {
      to: emailParam,
      from: 'ty@mailfence.com',
      subject: 'Just a quick note',
      text: `<p> hello ${agent.parameters.name} </p>`,
      html: `<p> hello ${agent.parameters.name} </p>`,
    };
    console.log(msg);
    sgMail.send(msg);
     
    agent.add(`Got it, sending to ${agent.parameters.email}!`);
    agent.add(new Suggestion(`Quick Reply`));
    agent.add(new Suggestion(`Suggestion`));
     }
  
    
  // Run the proper function handler based on the matched Dialogflow intent name
  let intentMap = new Map();
  intentMap.set('112correctemail.sendemail', sendEmail);
  agent.handleRequest(intentMap);
});
```

Using this code the sendEmail function executes properly - an email is sent, and the first comment from agent.add is sent to the user. However, the following new suggestions are not shown.

Does anyone have idea why it isn't working? I can use a card as a workaround, but it's not consistent with the rest of the bot and I think I can only do one button. Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Solved, the issue was that the code was displaying suggestions in Dialogflow(showed up in the console) but Facebook wasn't recognising it. The solution was to add a custom payload and specify Facebook as an agent.

```
 let payload = {
        text: `Is there anything else I can help you with?`,
        quick_replies: [
            {
                content_type: "text",
                title: `No, all set`,
                payload: "No, all set",
            },
                      {
                content_type: "text",
                title: `Back to menu`,
                payload: "Back to menu",
            }
        ]
    }; 

agent.add(new Payload(agent.FACEBOOK, payload, {sendAsMessage: true, rawPayload: false}));
```

Found out how to do this by visiting [this link](https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-fulfillment-nodejs/issues/146).